# Using iTunes match, my collection seems peppered with songs that cut out before their full length

Tags: iphone, itunes-match

Using iTunes match, my collection seems peppered with songs that cut out before their full length.

An example: A song would be 5 minutes long, the song timer would show it as being 5 minutes long, but after 3 minutes, the song just cuts out and there's nothing playing for the remaining 2 minutes.

Has anyone else encountered this? Better yet resolved it?

Comment: first thing to ask, have you checked your internet connection?

Comment: Yes - it's fine; these were re-downloaded and no interruptions were reported. Also I would expect itunes to tell me if a download was interrupted.

Comment: and are you listening to these on a Mac or iDevice?

Comment: Both -- iPhone and iTunes (on Win7)

Comment: and the issue is on both? or just one?

Comment: Sorry -- both it seems to be the file itself. However, if I deleted and redownload it, it's fine - I just don't want to have to do this for my 16gb+ worth of files :-) ....

Comment: I've had download and upload corruption on a small handful of files. And this is why I haven't really gone crazy with iTunes match upgrades yet except with a small number of albums.

Comment: I had the same thing on one track from an album I bought on iTunes last week. The customer advisor told me to redownload it, which worked. So maybe this is a general problem with iTunes.

Comment: I've just set up a new iTunes match against a new iPhone, and am having the same problem as described here. Re-downloading doesn't seem to fix it. Also worth noting - deleting the song from iTunes, and then downloading from match on my Mac produces a working song - it is only the phone that has trouble.

Comment: Are they **matched songs** or **uploaded songs**?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the file is corrupt, try another file. If the file is corrupt delete it and download it again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the “Get Info” screen and go to the “Options” tab. See if you have accidentally added a Stop Time (the box will be checked and/or the text field will say 3:00).

Just something to check!